# Dynamic Date and Time Filter: After 5:00 PM In Previous Day

Tags: powerquery

I am trying to creat a filter that will pull every account that has been set up after 5:00 PM from the previous day. The date and time exist in the same row. I have created a filter that works for the day but the next day, it pulls for two days. For example, here is what it looks like right now:

= Table.SelectRows(#"Sorted Rows", each [Driver ID] > #datetime(2021, 12, 29, 17, 0, 0))

I have tried changing it to the following so it would dynamically change as the days pass:

= Table.SelectRows(#"Sorted Rows", each DateTime.From([Driver ID]) > Date.AddDays(DateTime.From(Driver ID), -1))

But when I do this I get the following error:

Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value #datetime(2021, 12, 30, 0, 5, 0) to type Function.
Details:
Value=12/30/2021 12:05:00 AM
Type=[Type]

I have made sure the column type is in Date/Time format but that doesn’t seem to help.

Has anybody ran into this issue and know a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Sorted Rows", each Date.IsInPreviousNDays([DriverID], 1) and Time.From([DriverID])> #time( 17, 0, 0))
```

Comment: That looks like it worked! No accounts were set up yesterday due to the Holiday but it came up blank instead of an error! I will make sure either tomorrow or Monday but I consider this a win at the moment. Thank you, thank you, thank you!